# How can I observe what low-level system functions support a specific peripheral (specifically the internal camera on an iMac)?

Tags: macos, mojave, recovery, camera, kernel-extensions

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351787/disable-apple-facetime-camera-kernel-module) asks about disabling the FaceTime Camera kernel module, but has no answers. I have a similar goal, and I'd like to chase down what might be loading in support of the camera's hardware/interface. Being familiar with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, is there a similar way to trace what loads in support of the camera's hardware / interface stream?

For the record, I have tried disabling (moving/deleting from `/System/Library/Extensions`):
- `AppleCameraInterface.kext`
- `AppleiSight.kext`
- `IOVideoFamily`
... and moving (deleting) `/Library/CoreMediaIO`

None of these have disabled the camera (testing by opening the Zoom conferencing application).

(I've also tried following [this post](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/macos-disable-webcam-mac/) which is a suggestion on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112963/how-do-i-deactivate-my-microphone-and-isight-for-security-reasons).)

Comment: Black electrical tape.  "safe & effective"  overtime there have been reports about hacking the camera.  no hacks have gotten around tape.

Comment: @historystamp Fair enough, and if that were the only goal I may be able to settle there, but I'm looking to grow my knowledge of administrating the system. The goal (and the question) is not solely to disable the camera, but this question is specifically asking how to trace what modules are loaded and used by a given app. I could just as easily have asked about tracing underlying hardware/kernel modules used by Audacity (an audio recording/processing app) or any other app. The camera question was a good jumping off point for me to begin my search...

Comment:  You will find some interesting stuff with this google query "trace macos os events"  check out dtrace